# r studio won't start on remote desktop ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, remote-desktop, linux-mint

I have one computer with ubuntu 14.04 and another with windows 8. 
I connect to the ubuntu computer over SSL via XRDP using the mint desktop overlay.

I can start R studio when using the "local" desktop. However, via the remote desktop, i can start any program, but not R studio.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there are more elegant solutions but for now the answer is:

```
sudo su
```

Which puts the user into root.